# Canonical Basis and Transformations in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I know that it's possible to build the matrix of a linear transformation **knowing only where the canonical basis** $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}$ **is sent by the transformation**.
I used this property to build for example a reflection matrix.

What i don't understand is why (formally and mathematically ) this property can be exploited in Linear Algebra and which are the hidden consequences of this possibility. I would be happy to consult a precise exposition of this fact. Can you help me ?

Comment: The short answer: it’s a straightforward consequence of linearity of the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more general statement is the following.

> Let $V$ and $W$ be $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces and $T:V\rightarrow W$ a linear map. Let $\alpha=\left\{v_i\mid i\in I\right\}$ be a basis of $V$. Then $T$ is completely determined by knowing $T(v_i)$ for every $v_i\in \alpha$.

**Proof:** Let $v\in V$. Since $\alpha$ is a basis, we can write $v$ uniquely as a finite linear combination of the basis elements, i.e. $v=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_iv_i$ for unique $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{F}$ and only finitely many $\lambda_i$ are nonzero. Then \begin{eqnarray}
 T(v) &=& T(\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_iv_i)\\
      &=& \sum_{i\in I}\lambda_iT(v_i).
\end{eqnarray}$\square$

To say this a bit differently, suppose that $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$, then we only need to know $T$ on $n$ independent vectors to completely known what $T$ is doing. Aren't linear maps much easier than general functions? :)

There are many consequences to this fact. The most important is that you can choose which basis might help you in a certain problem. Let me give you an example:

Suppose that $S$ is the reflection about the plane $W$ generated by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ in the direction of the line $U$ generated by $(1,1,1)$. Determine $S(x,y,z)$.

This might be an annoying problem untill you realize that $S$ is linear and it suffices to know $S$ on a basis. Notice that $S(w)=w$ for all $w\in W$ and $S(u)=-u$ for all $u\in U$. Then take a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of a basis of $W$ and $U$, then we know $S$ completely. To find $S(x,y,z)$ we only need to write $(x,y,z)$ w.r.t. the basis that we choose.

Moreover, the basis chosen above is an example of an eigenbasis which leads you to diagonalization of linear maps. In short, almost everything you do in linear algebra starts from the realization that linear maps are determined by their action on a basis. The fact that linear maps correspond to matrices (after a choice of bases and in the finite-dimensional setting) is an immediate consequence as well.

Comment: In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1XeKUOuLzc&t=346s  a reflection matrix is build considering only the canonical basis. What assure us that , if the canonical basis is correctly reflected throght a line, then every other point in the plane will be correctly reflected ??? What i mean is that: ok, with this matrix the canonical basis is correctly reflected, but maybe if i apply the matrix to some points, the result can be different from reflection, since i build the matrix considering only the canonical basis

Comment: That's exactly the first statement in my answer. In the video the speaker is considering a (orthogonal) reflection about a certain line. This reflection $S$ is a linear transformation $S:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Hence it suffices to know what $S$ does on a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to know $S$ completely. Indeed, in the video they calculate $S(1,0)$ and $S(0,1)$. Then $S(x,y)=S(x(1,0)+y(0,1))$. The latter is equal to $xS(1,0)+yS(0,1)$ by linearity of $S$. Thus we know what $S(x,y)$ is.

Comment: Also, notice the canonical basis is a bad basis to consider for that problem. Indeed, the video needs a lot of computations and one really needs to think about what's happening. There is a much more convenient basis to consider. Can you see which one?